# Proper implementation of generic repository

Tags: c#, interface

What can be done better in this code?  I am sure it's not missing much.

You can copy and paste the whole thing in LinqPad; it's all there.

```
public interface IRep<T>
{
    List<T> GetAll();
}

public interface IEntity
{
    int Id{get;set;}
}

public class Customer: IEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}

public class Product: IEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public decimal Price {get;set;}
}

public class RepProduct: IRep<Product>
{
    public List<Product> GetAll()
    {
        List<Product> list = new List<Product>();
        list.Add(new Product() {Id=1, Code = "burger", Price = 2.99M});
        list.Add(new Product() {Id=1, Code = "fries", Price = 1.99M});
        list.Add(new Product() {Id=1, Code = "pepsi", Price = 1.99M});
        return list;
    }
}

public class RepCustomer: IRep<Customer>
{
    public List<Customer> GetAll()
    {
        List<Customer> list = new List<Customer>();
        list.Add(new Customer() {Id=1,Name="Fred", Age=44   });
        list.Add(new Customer() {Id=2,Name="Victoria", Age=13   });
        list.Add(new Customer() {Id=3,Name="Kiefer", Age=10 });
        return list;}
}

void Main()
{

    IRep<IEntity> rep = null;



}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get it to work, use `IEnumerable<T>` instead of `List<T>` as it's covariant:

```
public interface IRep<out T>
{
    IEnumerable<T> GetAll();
}

public interface IEntity
{
    int Id { get; set; }
}

public class Customer: IEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}

public class Product: IEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public decimal Price {get;set;}
}

public class RepProduct: IRep<Product>
{
    public IEnumerable<Product> GetAll()
    {
        List<Product> list = new List<Product>();
        list.Add(new Product() {Id=1, Code = "burger", Price = 2.99M});
        list.Add(new Product() {Id=1, Code = "fries", Price = 1.99M});
        list.Add(new Product() {Id=1, Code = "pepsi", Price = 1.99M});
        return list;
    }
}

public class RepCustomer: IRep<Customer>
{
    public IEnumerable<Customer> GetAll()
    {
        List<Customer> list = new List<Customer>();
        list.Add(new Customer() {Id=1,Name="Fred", Age=44   });
        list.Add(new Customer() {Id=2,Name="Victoria", Age=13   });
        list.Add(new Customer() {Id=3,Name="Kiefer", Age=10 });
        return list;
    }
}

void Main()
{
    IRep<IEntity> rep = null;

    rep = new RepCustomer();
    Console.WriteLine(rep.GetAll());

    rep = new RepProduct();
    Console.WriteLine(rep.GetAll());
}
```

Comment: YES!!!!!!!!!!!! i spent hours looking for the solution.. THANKS A LOT

Comment: What is the OUT for in <out T>

Comment: That indicates the type parameter for the interface is covariant, that is, it can accept type `T` and subclasses of `T` as well. That's the secret sauce here.

Comment: You have no idea how hard i tried to make this code work.. you really helped me out.. thanks a lot again

Comment: As soon as i get my rep up, I'll vote up your answer as well

Comment: Much appreciated :)

Comment: @RedSoxFred: As a more intuitive explanation of the purpose of covariance: It's illegal to pass `List<Dog>` to method expecting a `List<Mammal>` because the method might try to add a Cat to the list (as this is legal with a `List<Mammal>`).  It's legal to pass `IEnumerable<Dog>` to a method expecting `IEnumerable<Mammal>` because there is no way to add entries to an `IEnumerable`.  It is still possible to pull entries out, but an `IEnumerable<Dog>` will never contain non-mammals.  Hence, you use the keyword `out` to say that you plan to pull stuff out (but not put stuff in).